# Unwanted A circumflex in the text

Tags: overleaf, text

For some reason, when I try to write the following text in my thesis:
"as well as some early primordial accretion processes"

I get an unwanted A circumflex:
[image: Image showing the unwanted A circumflex]

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like some invisible unicode char. Delete and retype.

Comment: A-circumflex 99 times out of 100 means you have a UTF-8 document being processed as a legacy 8-bit encoding such as latin-1

Comment: And how I can change it?

Comment: What is the minimal complete example (code .tex) where you see the A circumflex?

Comment: @SeanMiranda as Ulrike said you can most likely change/fix this by going to the sentence in your source, put the cursor after _accretion_ for example, press backspace until the words _accretion_ and _primordal_ are gone, then type _primordal accretion_ again.

Comment: I tried it and it works! Thanks Ulrike!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments.